# How to use django and mysql?

Tags: mysql, django, migration

I want to use django with mysql but it alwyase give me error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.
```

So I tried to download with :

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

But it give me :

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

And when I tried to download visual studio it doesn't work, I'm using windows 7 32 bits, I tried it give the windows that it's downloading but it always suddenly stop and it doesn't download.

So I want to know if there is any visual studio for windows 7 or can I install the C++ package directly without installing visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get that message because pip tries to compile the plugin from C++ source code. Either you install the correct dependencies or you can use pymysql which writen in python, no compilation is required.

```
python3 -m pip install PyMySQL

# in your settings file, put this at the top
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

# now you can use 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
```

Comment: It stiil dosen"t work I have to update Pymysql from 0.9.3

Comment: it gives me this error     raise ImproperlyConfigured('mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have %s.' % Database.__version__)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.